# filtering output

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

```
for i in $(cat HPE_FRAMES_IP); do  ssh Reports@$i showsys | awk '{print $2,$5}' | column -t ; ssh Reports@$i showpd -degraded -failed | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5}' ; done | grep -v "MiB" | grep -v "total"
--Name---  Nodes
AN4ZX8401  MXN6232L4X
No PDs listed
----Name-----  Nodes
bga1ZX84-3128  4C17253128
No PDs listed
---Name---  Nodes
ZZ2ZX20841  CZ3741XP9X
No PDs listed
--Name---  Nodes
ZZ2ZX8401  MXN6102C7F
No PDs listed
--Name---  Nodes
ZZ2ZX8402  2MT814A12A
No PDs listed
--Name---  Nodes
CR3ZX8401  2M263601BJ
Id CagePos Type State
175 9:15:0 FC failed
---Name---  Nodes
ZZZZX20841  CZ3741X5K8
Id CagePos Type State
18 4:2:0 SSD degraded
-------Name-------  Nodes
ZZZZX8401_Full_DNA  MXN54823JY
No PDs listed
--Name---  Nodes
ZZZZX8402  MXN6102CAF
No PDs listed
-------Name-------  Nodes
ZZZZX8403_Full_DNA  MXN6192JEW
No PDs listed
```

following code gives desired output however I need to redirect this output in a CSV file with below format

I want to print output only when there's an actual output which has degraded or failed for showpd & showsys command.

desired output should be:

```
--Name---,Nodes
CR3ZX8401,2M263601BJ
Id,CagePos,Type,State
175,9:15:0,FC,failed

---Name---,Nodes
ZZZZX20841,CZ3741X5K8
Id,CagePos,Type,State
18,4:2:0,SSD,degraded
```

Question updated with below

showpd output can have multiple degrraded and failed output in that case printing with -B3 will not do... what if  pattern below is output

```
'---Name---,Nodes 
FM1HP20841,CZ3741X5K8 
Id,CagePos,Type,State 
18,4:2:0,SSD,degraded 
18,4:2:1,SSD,failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
for i in $(cat HPE_FRAMES_IP); do ssh Reports@$i showsys | awk '{print $2","$5}' ; ssh Reports@$i showpd -degraded -failed | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$5}' ; done | grep -v "MiB" | grep -v "total" | egrep -B3 "failed|degraded" | sed 's/---Name/\n---Name/g' > file.csv
```

- just wrap the comma with double quotes in `awk`
- remove `column`
- then do extended grep with the keywords
- `-B3` will print the 3 lines before the matching keyword
- `sed` is to add new line before "Name" as expected output

Comment: I would use `printf "%s,%s\n",` option in awk.

Comment: showpd output can have multiple degrraded and failed output in that case printing with -B3 will not do... what if below is the output pattern below is output                                                                                                                   '---Name---,Nodes
FM1HP20841,CZ3741X5K8
Id,CagePos,Type,State
18,4:2:0,SSD,degraded
18,4:2:1,SSD,failed
18,4:2:6,SSD,degraded`

Comment: @user3016638 can u update the same in question

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: @msp9011 can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Grep will help here :

```
for i in $(cat HPE_FRAMES_IP); do  ssh Reports@$i showsys | awk '{print $2,$5}' | column -t ; ssh Reports@$i showpd -degraded -failed | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5}' ; done | grep -v "MiB" | grep -v "total" | grep -B 4 -iE "failed|degraded"
```

### Modifications:

Pipe the output with **grep -B 4 -iE "failed|degraded"**

Comment: OP also wants to convert the result to a CSV format.